# How can we get SBJSON connectionDidFinishLoading method inside array data in another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to get background class array or dictionary data in MainViewController class and my code is below please help me somebody with example code

backGroundClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JSON.h"

@protocol MyConnectioDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didRecieveResponse:(id)aCollection;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(weak, nonatomic)id<MyConnectioDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

backGroundClass.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableData * webData;
    NSURLConnection * connection;
    NSMutableArray * array;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSURL * url  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"];

    NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [webData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString * allDataDictionbary = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary * responseString = [allDataDictionbary JSONValue];

    NSArray * allTweets = [responseString objectForKey:@"loans"];


    for (NSDictionary * obj in allTweets) {

        NSDictionary * act=[obj objectForKey:@"location"];
        NSDictionary * act1 = [ act objectForKey:@"geo"];
        NSString * level = [act1 objectForKey:@"pairs"];
        [array addObject:level];
    }

    [delegate didRecieveResponse:array];

    NSLog(@"act array is %@",array);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];   
}
@end
```

Now i want to get this array data in my mainview class

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<MyConnectioDelegate>

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
{
    ViewController * v1;
    NSArray * mainArray;
}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mainArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    v1 = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    v1.delegate = self;
    [self didRecieveResponse:mainArray];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)didRecieveResponse:(id)aCollection
{
    [mainArray arrayByAddingObject:aCollection];

     NSLog(@"the elements are %@",mainArray);
}

@end
```

i am loading that array data in my mainviewcontroller but array showing empty please help me somebody

Comment: Put a break point in at `[delegate didRecieveResponse:array];` and check the value of delegate. Is delegate nil?

Comment: please give me suggestions with example code

Comment: if anybody know about this please help me